# How to get word count in overleaf?

Tags: word-count, count

how can I get a word count on overleaf, of like a particular section? Can I highlight a section for example or a paragraph and get the word count?

Comment: Overleaf has already answered this on their own website: https://www.overleaf.com/learn/how-to/Is_there_a_way_to_run_a_word_count_that_doesn%27t_include_LaTeX_commands%3F